# How to scan documents in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to scan documents in a flutter with crop and editing? I am working in an app which required documents scanning and creating a PDF file. I have come across only paid solution that satisfy the requirements and in other solution we have to individually click image crop and store using different library.

Is there any single open source library using which we can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I created a Flutter plugin for iOS and Android.
Its based on VNDocumentCameraViewController and Intents and returns the cropped images. Feel free to contribute.
https://pub.dev/packages/cunning_document_scanner

If you want to create PDFs, you can use another plugin after cropping. e.g. https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know whether it is still relevant for you, but here is an article guiding you through the integration of the scanning function in your Flutter app with the Docutain SDK, which is pretty descriptive and easy to follow and also links to the relevant sources:

https://sdk.docutain.com/blogartikel/how-to-create-a-flutter-document-scanner